# Помогите пожалуйста подправить мой код. Программа, которая считает количество вхождений в текст каждого символа

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

Нужна программа, которая считает количество вхождений в текст каждого символа.

Вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string text = "", symbol = "";
    int count[256] = { 0 };
    int f = 0;

    //считываем текст
    cout << "Input the text:" << endl;
    getline(cin, text); 

    //меняем заглавные буквы на строчные
    transform(text.begin(), text.end(), text.begin(), tolower); 

    //считаем количество вхождений каждого символа
    //(если посчитали, то заменяем на '^')
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
    {
        if (text[i] != '^') 
        {
            symbol += " ";

            symbol[f] = text[i];
            count[f]++;
            text[i] = '^';
            for (int j = i + 1; j < text.length(); j++)
            {
                if (text[j] != '^' && text[j] == symbol[f])
                {
                    text[j] = '^'; 
                    count[f]++;
                }

            }
            f++;
        }

    }

    //выводим символ и его количество вхождений в текст
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < symbol.length(); i++) cout << symbol[i] << "\t";
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < symbol.length(); i++) cout << count[i] << "\t";
    cout << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

1) Почему-то заглавные буквы не меняются на строчные.

2) Не знаю, как упорядочить при выводе символы по количеству их вхождений (по убыванию).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Функция `tolower` не будет работать с русскими буквами. Наверное, должна, но я не слышал, чтоб где работала.

А у вас я бы собирал массив с символами сразу, а потом сортировал ([вот проверка, что код работает](https://rextester.com/GTI35987)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string text = "", symbol = "";
    struct data {
        char c;
        int  count;
    } count[256];

    for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        count[i].c = i;
        count[i].count = 0;
    }

    //считываем текст
    cout << "Input the text:" << endl;
    getline(cin, text); 

    //меняем заглавные буквы на строчные
    transform(text.begin(), text.end(), text.begin(), tolower);

    //считаем количество вхождений каждого символа
    //(если посчитали, то заменяем на '^')
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
    {
        count[text[i]].count++;
    }

    sort(count,count+256,[](const data& d1, const data& d2){ return d1.count > d2.count; });

    //выводим символ и его количество вхождений в текст
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        if (count[i].count)
            cout << count[i].c << " : " << count[i].count<< endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: причем тут русские буквы? Их по моему вообше нет

Comment: @ARHovsepyan У ТС первый вопрос про заглавные, и "7пар" точно русские. А с английскими буквами без проблем, они преобразуются как надо (как минимум в моей студии...)

Comment: а мне кажется  "7nap"  это на русском "7нап". Просто не вижу где логка: сообщение вывести на английском, а текст вводить кирилицей

Comment: ну и зачем вы читаете  256 символов, потом еще и считаете количество каждого? Не то...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan У ТС не переводится в нижний регистр потому, что буквы русские. Я не читаю 256 символов, я считаю число вхождений каждого символа из text (цикл после transform).

Comment: @ARHovsepyan См. https://rextester.com/GTI35987